# segmentation fault in fgets, trying to run shell command in c program

Tags: c, linux, popen

```
dev_list* somefunc()
{
    FILE* ExecutionResult;
    int deviceCount;
    int deviceIndex[50];
    char cmdExecute[50],finalOutputCmd[1000],outputCmd[100];
    int i;
    int bytes = 0;
    char* temp = 0;
    sprintf(cmdExecute,"%s\n" "ls -l");
    printf("command = %s\n",cmdExecute);
    ExecutionResult = popen(cmdExecute,"r");
    memset(finalOutputCmd,0,sizeof(finalOutputCmd));

    deviceCount = 0;
    deviceIndex[deviceCount] = 0;
    if ( ExecutionResult )
    {
        if (fgets(outputCmd, sizeof(outputCmd)-1, ExecutionResult) == NULL)             {
            printf("no bytes read\n");
            bytes += (sizeof(outputCmd)-1);                                 
        }
    }
    printf("hello %d,%d\n",i,bytes);
    return  0; //deviceList;
}
```

why there is seg fault on fgets? I run a shell command inside pipe, whose output is directed in a file. But when I am trying to read back, there is seg fault

Comment: `sprintf(cmdExecute,"%s\n", "ls -l");`

Comment: The only thing I can see is that in `bytes += (sizeof(outputCmd)-1);` you do not know if that number of bytes were read: that is the size of the buffer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  To clarify what I think @szpal is trying to say, you're missing a comma in the `sprintf()` call he points out.  On the other hand, I don't see why you're using `sprintf()` in the first place, instead of `strcpy()` or just using the string literal directly.

Comment: Yes John, you are right.

Comment: You are reading the value of `i` without ever having set it.  This produces undefined behavior, which *could* be a segfault, but is much more likely  to be harmless in this case.

Comment: I can't reproduce your segfault, and I don't see any reason to think that a segfault in `fgets()` is plausible.  I could, however, believe that the `sprintf()` discussed above segfaults, because the format given in (the original version of) it contains a field specifier without a corresponding argument.

Comment: To elaborate on those comments, in C the expression `"A" "B"` creates a single string `"AB"`. So the call to `sprintf` without a comma passes a format string `"%s\nls -l"` but no argument for the `%s` format specifier.

Comment: And in fact, MSVC issues a compiler warning about this: "not enough arguments passed for format string". So I hope you have all compiler warnings enabled ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I had done a strcat, it was the cause. I increased the size of finalOutputCmd[1000] to 50,000.